# Tool to migrate all pages from Confluence to Umbraco

Tags: umbraco, confluence

My company currently has a lot of pages in Confluence (cloud version). Nothing complicated - organized in spaces, many pages have sub pages, some pages have images.

We're now looking at moving our pages to an Umbraco CMS, hosted on our own servers.

Are there tools that will copy the pages in our Confluence account to an Umbraco instance?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a tool specifically for that, but there's a tool for the import of content called CMSImport

https://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/cmsimport/

Comment: CMS Import lets you write custom importers, so you should be able to do what you want. If you can export the data from Confluence as XML, which it looks like you can do: https://confluence.atlassian.com/confcloud/export-content-to-word-pdf-html-and-xml-724764824.html then it might work out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

**HOW TO TRANSFER CONFLUENCE TO UMBRACO**

As Umbraco is essentially free, there would be no external cost to setting up a trial. Take one space & export it into XML from there you can derive a document type structure that would support the space, something like:

- space

  - pages

    - blog pages (inheriting from page)
    - retrospective pages (inheriting from page)
    - other standard confluence page types ...
  - assets

When you have a document type structure you could use CMSImport (https://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/cmsimport/) to create pages that map to the confluence page types & going forward you can continue to create the same types of pages as you did in Confluence.

After that its a case of developing the template designs to show the pages.

**WHY YOU PROBABLY SHOULDN'T TRANSFER CONFLUENCE TO UMBRACO**

That said I've used Umbraco for years as well as Confluence & I'm not sure that they are sufficiently similar to migrate between. I'd say Confluence is more similar to a document store/wiki/blogging system than Umbraco which is an extensible web content management system.

The guy who runs Umbraco, Niels Hartvig, has said a few times over the years that if you are building a blog then Umbraco is probably the wrong option (eg https://our.umbraco.org/forum/using/ui-questions/5226-Which-blog-platform-do-you-use#comment-19128) & I would say by extension that building a document store/wiki/blogging system is not playing to Umbraco's strengths.

Basecamp, some kind of wiki platform, slack etc - there are dozens of options in this space that would probably do the job without an ongoing maintenance cost that would probably result from the Umbraco option.

Comment: To your point that Confluence is a wiki while Umbraco is a CMS - yes, you're probably right. However, my company is using Confluence to store help items. As in, Confluence is being used to store content, not as a blogging engine. Hence the idea to migrate to a proper CMS, such as Umbraco.

Comment: Seeing that both Confluence and Umbraco are popular products, I hoped that somebody had already created some program to translate from a Confluence export to an Umbraco import - so I don't have to figure it out myself.

Comment: @user1147862 The doc types in Umbraco must be setup to match the import data from Confluence. Now it would be simple enough to create an import from Confluence if Confluence hasn't been extended & no-one has used the macro extensions to complicate things. But I think that most Confluence setups are more complex so wouldn't fit a simple vanilla import. So building a Confluence to Umbraco tool may only work in the simplest cases.